# Financial calculation with JavaScript (What´s wrong?)

Tags: javascript, math, financial

I'm trying to make a financial calculation, but there's something wrong.

JS Code:

```
function count (){

var coda = 1.500;
var codb = 15;
var codc = 0.06;
var codx = 1;

var result = (codc/codx(codx-((codx+codc)*-codb)))*coda;

alert(result);


}
```

---

Message: undefined

Comment: `codx(...)` is parsed as invocation of `codx` function, but it is not a function.

Comment: Use better variable names. `cod[abcx]` is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `*` operator, so the compiler tries to call `codx` as a function.

To fix your computation, add the `*` operator as follow:

```
function count (){

    var coda = 1.500;
    var codb = 15;
    var codc = 0.06;
    var codx = 1;

    var result = (codc/codx * (codx - ((codx+codc)*-codb)))*coda;
    //                      ^

    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line
`var result = (codc/codx(codx-((codx+codc)*-codb)))*coda;`

You try to execute the 2nd `codx` as a function (`codx()`). I guess you miss an operand there.

Try for example:
`var result = (codc/codx / (codx-((codx+codc)*-codb)))*coda;`

Answer (score 0):

Missing * symbol? codx is being used as a fuction as a result.

```js
var coda = 1.500;
var codb = 15;
var codc = 0.06;
var codx = 1;

var result = (codc/codx*(codx-((codx+codc)*-codb)))*coda;

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic but you should never use floating point arithmetic in financial calculations. Instead calculate by integer cents and then format for viewing as you like.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

It is better to split the mathematical calculation.

Example:

```
function count (){

var coda = 1.500;
var codb = 15;
var codc = 0.06;
var codx = 1;

var res1 = ((codx+codc)*-codb);
var res2 = codx-res1;
var result = (codc/codx*res2)*coda;

alert(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = function () {
 var coda = 1.5; var codb = 15; var codc = 0.06; var codx = 1;
 var result = (codc/codx ** here ** (codx-((codx+codc)* - codb))) *  coda;    
 console.log(result);
}
```

P.S you have to put something after **codx** it's seen by javascript as an undefined function.

Answer (score 0):

If this relates to paying down a loan at interest `i` per payment period, then you get that after `n` payments at a rate of `r` the reduced principal is

```
p*(1+i)^n-r*(1+i)^n-r*(1+i)^(n-1)-...-r*(1+i) 
=
p*(1+i)^n - (1+i)*((1+i)^n-1)/i*r
```

If that is to be zero, loan repaid, then the necessary rate computes as

```
r = i/((1+i)*(1-(1+i)^(-n))) * p
```

which is in some aspects similar, in other fundamental aspects different from your formula.

```js
var p = 1.500;
var n = 15;
var i = 0.06;
var x = 1+i;

var result = i/( x*( 1-Math.pow(x,-n) ) )*p;

alert(result);
```